# Magento 2 : whatever changes I did are reset after 1 or 2 days

Tags: magento2

I have a question I am working on my client's site and he migrated the site from Magento 1.9 to  Magento 2.1.0, also the magneto 2 theme from swissup lab is installed to site.

Basically, I need help in this, whatever changes I made to site it reverts after 1 or 2 days. Is this happen because I haven't created a child theme and do changes?

Changes like,

1. add smartchat script to header file.
2. add quantity increment decrement buttons to product, page and cart page.
3. add footer links etc.

I have done these changes to the files using template path hints and add code to files.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better not to edit Magento files directly and make the desired changes using modules.
Because, when a client will update his Magento or theme, you may lose the changes that were made.